# JMS Adapter adding namespace value xmlns=""

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces, jms, bpel

With SOA BPEL2.0, I am trying to map string to JMS outbound queue.

I am using simple xsd as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                      elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:element name="FullName" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Presently Queue message is produced as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><FullName xmlns="">
....
....
</FullName>
```

Where as desired queue message is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><FullName>
....
....
</FullName>
```

I am not using any xsl or so.

Any help or clue will be really great.

Answer (score 0):

Please try code bellow:

It removes all namespace definitions from the processed file but copies all other nodes and values: elements, attributes, comments, text and processing instructions.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <!-- Stylesheet to remove all namespaces from a document -->
    <!-- NOTE: this will lead to attribute name clash, if an element contains
        two attributes with same local name but different namespace prefix -->
    <!-- Nodes that cannot have a namespace are copied as such -->

    <!-- template to copy elements -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to copy attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to copy the rest of the nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks I am trying this with BPEL2.0 and it's not working. I am using below mentioned code here...

    <assign name="Transform1">
      <copy>
        <from>bpel:doXslTransform("xsl/NamespaceRemoval.xsl", $Invoke2_Produce_Message_InputVariable.body)</from>
        <to>$Invoke2_Produce_Message_InputVariable.body</to>
      </copy>
    </assign>

Comment: I found solution, I changed JMS adapter for Opaque then I converted whole XML to string and encoded XML string to Base64 using Base64Encoder and send this Base64 encoded value to Opaque JMS Queue. And get desired resultant message.